# Provisioned lambda correctly configured but not working as it should

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack-api

I've developed an app for Slack but I've been having trouble starting it for a while now.

For those who don't know, the slack api requires a response within 3 seconds for user interaction requests, if this time passes it generates an error and the application does not work as it should.

I came to solve this problem, creating a lambda that runs every 3 minutes, invoking the main lambda, but I don't think it's the best way to do it.

With that I decided to create a lambda with provisioned concurrency, leaving 2 lambdas started. I think it was the best choice.

Turns out it's not working as it should. When I make the call, the API gateway is pointing to $LATEST, causing it to start a new lambda and I get timeout errors.

The configuration was done correctly as you can see:
[image: *The alias is called Latest (currently in version 42)]

[image: I configured it to keep 2 active lambdas]

[image: The API is configured correctly and pointing to the created Alias]

Now when I make the calls it's creating a new container and pointing to the $LATEST version instead of pointing to the started lambdas. Version 42 lambdas receive one request or another at random as you can see in the logs. I really don't understand what's going on.

[image: *Logs]

Comment: You said that you created "a lambda that runs every 3 minutes, invoking the main lambda". I presume you mean that you used CloudWatch Events to schedule the Lambda function to be invoked every 3 minutes. Is that schedule still running?

Comment: @jarmod No, I removed this lambda because I believed that through provisioned concurrency I could solve the problem.

Comment: Related [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUHUTSmYGtQLGC3_ZE2VbGXA/lambda-provisioned-concurrency-for-latest-or-updating-api-gateway-to-refer-to-version) and [here](https://www.it-labs.com/provisioned-concurrency-for-aws-lambda-functions/) in case it's helpful.

Comment: It is already set up exactly as in the mentioned articles. As I showed in the print, I already have an alias pointing to the latest version and the api gateway pointing to the alias.